# WCF deserializes JSON epoch formatted timestamp incorrectly

Tags: c#, json, wcf, date, datetime

I have a WCF REST service with some method:

```
string FooBar(Foo bar);
```

Foo has a DateTime property inside of it.

On the other hand I have an Angular.js client. The client calls the service and formats the date to fit the needs of WCF. I use following function to format the dates:

```
function dateToWcf(input) {
    var d = new Date(input);
    if (isNaN(d)) return null;
    return '\/Date(' + d.getTime() + '-0000)\/';
}
```

(comes from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1698350.aspx?trying%20to%20pass%20a%20date%20value%20from%20json%20to%20a%20wcf%20service))

```
//Splitted date is a result of .split(".") function executed on input date in dd.MM.yyyy format
model.field = dateToWcf(new Date(splittedDate[2], splittedDate[1], splittedDate[0], 0, 0, 0));
```

The result of call is JSON with date field represented like that:

```
/Date(1455318000000-0000)/\
```

WCF service binds the dates, but in an incorrect way. It adds an offset, so dates from input are different than dates on output:

> 13.01.2016 -> 13.2.2016
>
> 31.01.2016 -> 2.3.2016

I'd understand if it would differ slightly, but a month is too big to be the difference of timezone. I know the date and time representation is a huge topic, but I can't find any easy answers to this behavior.

**UPDATE**

I've noticed the dateToWcf function produce somehow strange epoch values. [This](http://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html) on-line converter wasn't able to convert it well. I've modified to

```
function dateToWcf2(dateInString, dateFormat) {
    return '\/Date(' + moment.utc(dateInString, dateFormat).unix() + ')\/'
}
```

The result is even more frustrating. It returns proper epoch timestamp (for example `01.01.2016 -> 1451606400`), but WCF translates it completely incorrectly (`01.01.2016 -> 17.01.1970`).

**UPDATE2**

It seems to be all about three missing zeroes at the end of timestamp:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> (new-object DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0)).AddMilliseconds(1451606400)

Saturday, January 17, 1970 7:13:26 PM


PS C:\Users\Administrator> (new-object DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0)).AddMilliseconds(1451606400000)

Friday, January 1, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't WCF but java script. There are various ways of representing timestamp. Correct way to transform any format of date from input to WCF-acceptable form is this function:

```
function convertDateToWCFFormat(dateInString, dateFormat) {
        var noTimezone = '-0000';
        return '\/Date(' + moment.utc(dateInString, dateFormat).valueOf() + noTimezone + ')\/';
    }
```

[Momentjs java script library](http://momentjs.com/) is required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your javascript convert the DateTime to ISO 8601 standard.  That way you don't have to worry about time zones or anything.  WCF handles this format just fine!

```
function dateToWcf(input) {
    var d = new Date(input);
    if (isNaN(d)) return null;
    return d.toISOString(); // ISO 8601 format
}
```